# How to fetch hindi string from php file and set into android textview properly

Tags: android

I have a php file which contains hindi string i want to fetch exact string in android, it send some encoded value

abc.php:

```
<?php
    echo "शुभ प्रभात";
?>
```

in android:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message :+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

output i got:
[image]

i tried

```
 URLDecoder.decode
```

and also try

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "hindi.TTF");
homeTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
```

for set it into textview but nothing works for me.

assets:
[image]

Comment: Where have you placed the `hindi.TTF` file. Could you please attach the screenshot of your project structure if possible?

Comment: hi, i edit my question and add screenshot regarding assets

Comment: Just for ease would you put the `hindi.TTF` in a **new folder** (eg. fonts/hindi.TTF) inside assets and then troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the character set into your PHP file like

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Then after you can try to fetch JSON from your service it will give to you proper data. In your case for example

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    echo "शुभ प्रभात";
?>
```

Comment: you need to convert you string encoding for example "4KS24KWB4KStIOCkquCljeCksOCkreCkvuCkpA==" using base64
https://www.base64decode.org/ then after when data arise then decode reason behind that your data automatically converted into HTML entities.

Comment: if the answer is helpful then please accept it because contribute for make helpful for another one.